# PowerShell Calendar Popup

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to use the PowerShell script from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730942.aspx

After choosing a date and hitting enter, the variable $dtmDate has no data.  Please help.  Is it possible to add an OK/Cancel button?

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(243,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 

if ($dtmDate)
    {
        Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"
    }
```

Comment: Umm... That code runs perfectly fine on Powershell V2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dtmDate` has no value in the context of your if statement because that code isn't being executed on your enter keypress... the block in the context of `Add_KeyDown` is.  Try executing something like this instead:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$dtmDate = $null

# I've moved your Date printing logic into this function that can be called elsewhere.
Function Do-Work
{
    if ($dtmDate -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"
    }
}

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(243,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate = $objCalendar.SelectionStart        
            $objForm.Close()

            Do-Work
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

The new function `Do-Work` is defined outside of the scope of `Add_KeyDown`, but since we call it there it will get executed on your Enter keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add:

`New-Variable dtmDate -Option AllScope`

Comment: Welcome. This answer is very short. Please consider explaining how this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

New-Variable dtmDate -Option AllScope
$dtmDate = $null

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(190,190) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown(
    {
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
        $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
        $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown(
    {
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {$objForm.Close()}
    })

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 

if ($dtmDate) {Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate" -ForegroundColor Green}
```

The line "New-Variable dtmDate -Option AllScope" allows the variable to be brought outside of the form scope, so you can use it further in your script.

I left out the creation of a function for the write host. If you want to do it the proper way, create a function of the entire script block.
The above script will work in the way you want it to. It's working for me!